# apply custom class on breakpoint in react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to apply custom classes to the bootstrap components based on the size breakpoints.

I've been using media queries until now, but that seems little unreadable. I'd rather have it defined in the jsx.

Comment: what is your question specifically here